My character is incomplete when I render with the gpu in cycles
I'm trying to render my animation, but when I do, the character appears incomplete. For some reason, if I render with the CPU this doesn't happen.


Hello and welcome to BSE. Impossible to know without more information. Can you perhaps share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com
